# Error al parsear template en spring con thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Tengo unos items en una base de datos que debo mostrar en un html. Para eso utilizo un controller en spring para pasarle la info al html. en el html utilizo thymeleaf para ayudarme. El problema llega al momento de buscar un item especifico a traves de una id. El error es este:

```
> > [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template
> > "listaCamionetaIndividual": An error happened during template parsing
> > (template: "class path resource
> > [templates/listaCamionetaIndividual.html]")
> > 
> > org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened
> > during template parsing (template: "class path resource
> > [templates/listaCamionetaIndividual.html]")
> >         at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366)
> > ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
> > ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1401)
> > ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145)
> > ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084)
> > ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
> > ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> > ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
> > ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:4.0.FR]
> >         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> > ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:4.0.FR]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> > ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> > ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> > ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> > ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> > ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> > ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na] Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating
> > SpringEL expression: "camioneta.id" (template:
> > "listaCamionetaIndividual" - line 18, col 25)
> >         at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
> > ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
> >         at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         ... 48 common frames omitted Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception
> > evaluating SpringEL expression: "camioneta.id" (template:
> > "listaCamionetaIndividual" - line 18, col 25)
> >         at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:292)
> > ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]      
> >         at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:144)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:304)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]      
> >         at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:278)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:186)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:124)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:109)
> > ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
> >         at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:297)
> > ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
> >         at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:402)
> > ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
> >         at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseOpenElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:159)
> > ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
> >         at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:710)
> > ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
> >         at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
> > ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
> >         ... 50 common frames omitted Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:
> > Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type
> > 'java.util.Optional' - maybe not public or not valid?
> >         at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:217)
> > ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104)
> > ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:51)
> > ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:406)
> > ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:92)
> > ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:112)
> > ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:338)
> > ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:265)
> > ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]      
> >         ... 69 common frames omitted
> > 
> > 2022-06-14 11:36:34.286 ERROR 1452 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> > o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
> > servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
> > [Request processing failed; nested exception is
> > org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened
> > during template parsing (template: "class path resource
> > [templates/listaCamionetaIndividual.html]")] with root cause
> > 
> > org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:
> > Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type
> > 'java.util.Optional' - maybe not public or not valid?       
> >         at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:217)
> > ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104)
> > ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:51)
> > ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:406)
> > ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:92)
> > ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:112)
> > ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:338)
> > ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:265)
> > ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]      
> >         at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:144)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:304)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]      
> >         at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:278)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:186)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:124)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:109)
> > ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
> >         at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:297)
> > ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
> >         at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:402)
> > ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
> >         at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseOpenElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:159)
> > ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
> >         at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:710)
> > ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
> >         at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
> > ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
> >         at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
> > ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366)
> > ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
> > ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
> >         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1401)
> > ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145)
> > ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084)
> > ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
> > ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> > ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
> > ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:4.0.FR]
> >         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> > ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:4.0.FR]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> > ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> > ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> > ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> > ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> > ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> > ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> > ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
> >         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
```

El html luce asi:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Getting Started : Serving Web Content</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <p th:text="'hello!'"></p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>marca</th>
                <th>modelo</th>
                <th>precio</th>
                <th>stock</th>
        </tr>
            <tr th:object="${camioneta}">
                    <th th:text = "${camioneta.id}"></th>
                    <th th:text = "${camioneta.marca}"></th>
                    <th th:text = "${camioneta.modelo}"></th>
                    <th th:text = "${camioneta.precio}"></th>
                    <th th:text = "${camioneta.stock}"></th>
                    <th th:text = "${camioneta.color}"></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

el controller en cuestion es este:

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public String listarPorId(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("camioneta", repo.findById(id));
        return "listaCamionetaIndividual";
    }
```

para terminar re pregunto: cual de los procedimientos involucrados es lo que puede estar causar el error y como podria solucionarse.
**solucion ya encontrada por favor revisar seccion respuestas**

Comment: Por favor, elimina todos esos espacios `th:text = "$` debería verse `th:text="$`. Es un error de parseo en tu plantilla, no de tu controlador.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez eso es mas por buena practica? o puede llegar a afectar en algo?

Comment: Mis disculpas, ahora que leo el error, al parecer el problema radica en que repo.findById(id) te devuelve un opcional, no un objeto camioneta. De cualquier manera, por favor, evita esos espacios.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez ya elimine los espacios y logre a partir del optional retirar la id que necesitaba. Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: me alegra que resolvieras tu problema. Por favor, agrega una respuesta para futuros usuarios que busquen la pregunta. Por otro lado, ¿probaste si con los espacios funcionaba? Ahora me quedé con la duda. Hace un par de versiones según recuerdo no funcionaba, pero hace ya bastante que no uso thymeleaf.

Comment: Ahi agregue la solucion al problema con una breve explicacion. Intente en otro html que contiene el mismo formato y con los espacios funciona bien sin problemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solucion:

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/lista/{id}")
    public String listarPorId(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model) {
        Camioneta camioneta = null;
        Optional<Camioneta> camio = repo.findById(id);
        if (camio.isPresent()) {
            camioneta = camio.get();
        }
        model.addAttribute("camioneta", camioneta);
        return "listaCamionetaIndividual";
    }
```

como se ve al inicio declaro una variable camioneta y le doy un valor null como base. luego de eso busco el optional de camioneta y pregunto en una clausula if si se encuentra presente(osea si el optional contiene el objeto o no lo contiene) si el optional contiene un objeto le pido que lo consiga a traves del .get y a ese objeto lo guardo en la variable camioneta declarada al inicio. luego en el addAttribute declaro el nombre de camioneta con su valor correspondiente para ser usado en el html. **Agrego** que esto falla en caso de ser nulo. Para evitar eso deben meter el return y el model.addAtribute dentro del if y luego armar una clausula else con lo que sea que deban hacer en caso de que el optional sea null